# Spark Scala remove newline characters while trying to read and write kafka stream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am trying to read from Kafka stream and write it as csv which I am successful but I am facing an issue with newline character where if I try to create a table due to //n data is mismatching itself.

My data is in a format like this:-

```
{\"Request ID\": \"XXXX-XXXX\", \"Owner\": \"cam,Ash (acf)\", \"Request Description\": \"nasvote.\", \"Short Term Resolution\": \"\\u2011322\\tCRT cod. \\n\\u22e3026822\\tMa (completed 8/18)\\no\\tACDC confirmed materials pacted\\n\\u2dw02322\\tClaims Re1.\\no\\t\"}
```

While I try to write it as csv as string due to newline my data is ,

```
XXXX-XXXX,"cam,Ash (acf)",nasvote.,â€¢ CRT cod. 
â€¢ Ma (completed 8/18)
o ACDC confirmed materials pacted
â€¢ Claims Re1.
o
```

Special characters, newline, tab is acting on the data. I need to remove all that, tried `regexp_replace` getting errors if I try giving column argument saying ArrayOutOfBound, also tried creating schema and providing one it is saying like ,

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`Short Term Resolution`' given input columns: [key, jsontostructs(CAST(value AS STRING))];
```

Comment: Your data seems to be JSON, but has escape characters. Why? And why do you want CSV data?

Comment: I want to create a table on top of the data consumed from Kafka server. So I used spark first to write it into CSV and then used hive to create table.

Comment: Hive can read JSON too, or preferably Parquet. CSV should be avoided. Still doesn't answer why there's escape characters in your data

Comment: I am actually trying to consume kafka topic where I have the data in key value pair as mentioned above so I am working with Spark. 


Also, I was able to resolve this issue. I have done some transformations using regexp_replace before writing into csv. Thanks!